# Sum of products of elements chosen from couples

Tags: combinatorics

I have N couples of real numbers higher than 1.
Let's call them like (a0,b0), (a1,b1),...,(aN,bN)
I have a number R <= N.

I need the sum of all the possible products of N elements, chosing one from each couple but exactly R times the "b" element and N-R times the "a" element.
 Which is the best way to do it?

As an example:

(2,3), (5,7), (11,13)

N = 3, R = 2

I need 2x7x13 + 3x5x13 + 3x7x11

Thank you!

Wentu

Comment: So it is the coefficient of $x^R$ in $(a0+xb0)(a1+xb1)...(aN+xbN)$

Comment: Thank you very much. This same solution seems to come out for seemingly different problems that i encounter from time to time and i am never able to see when it is really applicable.